# Scrapy callback conditional on link class name

Tags: scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and I'm trying to build a crawler that parses the response depending on the class name of the  tag. I've seen in the docs that you can work with Rule() to define the callback function depending on the URL with allow and deny, but that doesn't work for me. What does work is that if an  tag has a certain class name (say "item"), that it should go to callback parse_item().

What I'm trying to achieve is that my crawler visits all website links from a base URL and depending on the class name of the  tag it should store that data.

So say:

- Base URL = example.com
- On this base URL there are 2 links:  and
- The crawler should visit both URLs and look for other links in there, but only for the link with class="item" I want to actually store the HTML of that page.

The LinkExtractor() has a function process_values(), that processes the values of the attr(). But I don't see how I can get this done. I've tried the following:

```
class NewSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'newspider'

    start_urls = ['https://example.com']

    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(attrs=('class',), process_value=(lambda x: True if (x == 'class_name') else False)), callback="parse_items"),)
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        # store data
```

Comment: With the information you provided there is very little anyone can do to help you.  At the very least update your question to include what the actual problem is... simply saying it's not working doesn't help.  What is it doing?  You would have much better chances of solving your problem if you included your actual code, a sample url to test it on, the output of your logs ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to callback parse_xxx if tag is xxx, you should pass a argument to default parse method to define the callback function, I had write a spider before to parse multi domain in one spider.For example:

```
def google(response):
    title = response.xpath('//title/text()')
    yield title

Class TestSpider(spiders.Spider):
    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(url='https://www.google.com', cb_kwargs={'parse_func':google})

    def parse(self, response, parse_func):
        parse_result = parse_func(response):
        for item in pares_result:
            yield item
```